# Unable to open axml with design view with Visual Studio 2015

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I created a new android layout file using visual studio 2015 and am unable to view with the designer that is built in to visual studio.

After selecting 'design' tab, I just see a waiting icon in the center of the view and it never finishes.  After a while, i have to close the design tab and open in xml editor.  The form is valid as it runs fine in emulator.

ideas?

Comment: Hey! There can be a few causes of this, most common are an incompatible Android tools install, an incorrect version of Java, or an out of memory error. Are you able to provide a screenshot of Tools > Android > Android SDK Manager (https://db.tt/lihaVoid) as well as logs from: %LOCALAPPDATA%\Xamarin\Logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve after uninstalling all platforms using Android SDK Manager and re-installing each platform 1 by 1.  If there is an issue with the installation nothing will be installed (note: watch the logs for errors and review after each platform is installed)

Initially, I did have to manually download SDK Manager and copy the tools folder to my existing installation.  I am not sure why my Tools folder was empty but after performing this step I could again run SDK Manager.